# The select is undefined even if I choose a valid option

Tags: php, jquery

*The select is undefined even if I choose a valid option*

```
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="rights">Rights</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="rs">
           <option>Alege...</option>
            <?php $reqRights = $conn->query("SELECT `IdRights`,`TitleRights` FROM Rights");
                while ($rowR = $reqRights->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $rowR['IdRights']?>"><?php echo $rowR['TitleRights']?></option> 
            <?php } ?>
       </select>
    </div>

    <script>
    <!--Start Update User by Admin-->
    function updatedata(str){
    var id = str;
    var username = $('#username'+str).val();
    var email = $('#email'+str).val();
    var name = $('#name'+str).val();
    var surname = $('#surname'+str).val();
    var rights = $('#rs option:selected').val();

            var datas="username="+username+"&email="+email+"&name="+name+"&surname="+surname+"&rights="+rights;

            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "app/admin_update_data_user.php?id="+id,
               data: datas
            }).done(function( data ) {
              $('#admininfo').html(data);
              viewdata();
            });
            }
        <!--End Update User by Admin-->
</script>
```

The result is : username=Admin&email=admin@ex.com&name=Admin&surname=Admin&rights=undefined

I do not understand why a favorable outcome ...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: instead of var rights = $('#rs option:selected').attr('value'); use $('#rs').val().

Comment: Stop editing the answer into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This code will be showing `undefined` for the first option . Because there is no value for that option.

```js
var rights = $('#rs option:selected').val();
alert(rights)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="rs">
  <option>Alege...</option>
  <option value="1">Admin</option>
  <option value="2">Manager</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But the first option is not selected.

Comment: @PreferenceBean that is what I was referring in my answer. If he is trying to select the first option it will be undefined since he is not using any value attribue.

Comment: _"The select is undefined even if I choose a valid option"_ Why would the OP choose the empty option and expect it to give a valid, non-empty result?